# How to Simply retrieve all the items and values in Firebase using Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code. I tried to retrieve it in the log then display it if it
is retrieved. But I think it doesn't seem the right way. And hoping someone could correct me, on how to easily retrieve all the items and values in firebase.

```
  final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("FirstRoot");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
//
//                    Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
//                    Object material = map.get("item");
//                    Object value = map.get("value");
//                    int v = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(value));
                    String material  = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("item").getValue());
                    Log.d("Item:", material);
//                    String item = dataSnapshot.child("item").getValue().toString();;
////                    Float valuee = Float.parseFloat(dataSnapshot.child("valuee").getValue().toString());
//                    entries.add(new PieEntry(13f, item));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: 1) Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. 2) When you run this code in a debugger and step through it line-by-line, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank's for the info about the tags because this is my first time to ask some questions in stackoverflow. On your q2 this is my friend's program and he said that when he debug the code it shows null or the values haven't retrieve.

Comment: So you want to read the value of item and value, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes like reading the items and values in the firebase and retrieve them.

Comment: Do you have any other similar values or you want to read only those two?

Comment: I think only those two under Data Collection on the given picture that I put above.

Comment: @AlexMamo but I guess the way my friend saves the data is wrong, right? he was actually working on a pie chart so he wanted the data here to be retrieved. By searching it by a specific date and also for the total.

Comment: What are the values of the other nodes that are not show in the picture?

Comment: @AlexMamo - My friend deleted the database because the database structure he created is wrong it's like creating a table inside another table. And to your question, all the items and values are the same, it's just that it is separated because of a specific date.

Comment: And we can disregard the pic now as it's not the correct structure of the database, but in general, I just need to retrieve the items and value from firebase.

Comment: @Ginoong. Flores Instead of looking for value event listener. You should retrieve the snapshot of all database reference.
Can you use this API Task<DataSnapshot> get()

Comment: @BaluSangem, Thanks! I'm going to try this one.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not so clear from the question where you want to store the data retrieved from firebase .This may work..Have a try....

```
final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("FirstRoot");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                  
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {

                            final String data1 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("data1").getValue())).toString();
                            final String data2 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("data2").getValue())).toString();
                            final String data3 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("data3").getValue())).toString();
                            final String data4 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("data4").getValue())).toString();

                            model_class model = new model_class(data1,data2,data3,data4);
                            //do whatever you want with your data
                             entries.add(new PieEntry(13f, data1));
                          
                        }
                       
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

If you want to read data from firebase cloud firestore you want to simple write this code.

```
// Get a Instance from FirebaseFirestore.
val db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    //Get the user current Id.
    val uId = auth.currentUser!!.uid
    //Instead of XYZ you have to write your collection name and Id in 
    //document.
    db.collection("XYZ").document(uId)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful){
               //When it is successful you have to do what you want as I have given example that you can understand better through this way you can get userName and you can set into your textView and you can read as many data as you can this is one example.
                val documentSnapShot = it.result
                val firstName = documentSnapShot.getString("first_name")
                tv_Set_ProfileName.text =firstName
                
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sure, If you learn from this please upvote.